# Round UIView bottom corners inside custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to round the bottom corners of a custom view inside a tableview cell. The code I'm using it's not working and I don't understand why...

So, I have a `UItableViewCell` and inside the `contentView` there is a custom view `containerView`. Inside that, on top, I have two labels and in the bottom another view. That view must have rounded bottom corners.

My code:

```
class HomeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var containerView: UIView!
var bottomDetailsView: UIView!
var titleLabel: UILabel!
var timeLabel: UILabel!

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: "tableCell")

    containerView = UIView()
    bottomDetailsView = UIView()
    timeLabel = UILabel()
    titleLabel = UILabel()


    self.contentView.addSubview(containerView)
    containerView.addSubview(bottomDetailsView)
    containerView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    containerView.addSubview(timeLabel)

    containerView.snp.makeConstraints({ (maker) in
        maker.top.equalTo(self.contentView.snp.top)
        maker.bottom.equalTo(self.contentView.snp.bottom)
        maker.left.equalTo(self.contentView.snp.left).inset(10)
        maker.right.equalTo(self.contentView.snp.right).inset(10)
    })

    bottomDetailsView.snp.makeConstraints { (maker) in
        maker.top.equalTo(containerView.snp.centerY).offset(30)
        maker.left.equalTo(containerView.snp.left)
        maker.right.equalTo(containerView.snp.right)
        maker.bottom.equalTo(containerView.snp.bottom)
    }

    timeLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (maker) in
        maker.centerX.equalTo(containerView.snp.centerX)
        maker.centerY.equalTo(containerView.snp.centerY).offset(10)
    }

    titleLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (maker) in
        maker.left.equalTo(containerView.snp.left).inset(10)
        maker.top.equalTo(containerView.snp.top).inset(10)
        maker.right.equalTo(containerView.snp.right).inset(10)
    }
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    bottomDetailsView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9607843161, green: 0.7058823705, blue: 0.200000003, alpha: 1)
    containerView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4666666687, green: 0.7647058964, blue: 0.2666666806, alpha: 1)
    containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
    timeLabel.font = timeLabel.font.withSize(24)
    timeLabel.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    titleLabel.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)

    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bottomDetailsView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 15, height: 15))
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.frame = bottomDetailsView.frame
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    bottomDetailsView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    bottomDetailsView.layer.mask = shapeLayer
}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

I'm using `SnapKit` for the auto-layout. The problematic code is

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bottomDetailsView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 15, height: 15))
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.frame = bottomDetailsView.frame
shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
bottomDetailsView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
bottomDetailsView.layer.mask = shapeLayer
```

I tried different combinations with this code, but can't get anything to work. It doesn't display absolutely nothing. If instead of `bottomDetailsView.layer.mask = shapeLayer` I write `bottomDetailsView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)` the view shows but without the corners rounded.

I don't remember what I did, but at certain point I achieved that I saw a black rounded layer on top of the view, but only if the cell was outside of the screen and then loaded again with `dequeueReuseableCell`. Every solution I found on the internet points to the same code I have, maybe it must be done somewhere else?

**EDIT 1:**

After the answers I got, I updated the code, and now it looks like this:

```
class HomeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var containerView: UIView!
var bottomDetailsView: BottomDetailsView!
var titleLabel: UILabel!
var timeLabel: UILabel!

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: "tableCell")

    containerView = UIView()
    bottomDetailsView = BottomDetailsView(frame: .zero)
    timeLabel = UILabel()
    titleLabel = UILabel()

    self.contentView.addSubview(containerView)

    containerView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    containerView.addSubview(timeLabel)
    containerView.addSubview(bottomDetailsView)

    containerView.snp.makeConstraints({ (maker) in
        maker.top.bottom.left.right.equalToSuperview()
    })

    titleLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (maker) in
        maker.height.equalTo(15)
        maker.top.left.right.equalTo(containerView)
        maker.bottom.equalTo(timeLabel.snp.top)
    }

    timeLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (maker) in
        maker.height.equalTo(34)
        maker.top.equalTo(titleLabel.snp.bottom)
        maker.centerX.equalTo(containerView.snp.centerX)
        maker.bottom.equalTo(bottomDetailsView.snp.top)
    }
    bottomDetailsView.snp.makeConstraints { (maker) in
        maker.top.equalTo(timeLabel.snp.bottom)
        maker.left.equalTo(containerView.snp.left)
        maker.right.equalTo(containerView.snp.right)
        maker.bottom.equalTo(containerView.snp.bottom)
    }
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    bottomDetailsView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9607843161, green: 0.7058823705, blue: 0.200000003, alpha: 1)

    containerView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4666666687, green: 0.7647058964, blue: 0.2666666806, alpha: 1)
    containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0

    timeLabel.font = timeLabel.font.withSize(24)
    timeLabel.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    titleLabel.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Also I made a subclass of UIView as Duncan C suggested:

```
class BottomDetailsView: UIView {
var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer!

//If the view's bounds change, update the shapeLayer's frame and also rebuild the path
override var bounds: CGRect {
    didSet {
        shapeLayer.frame = self.bounds
        createShapeLayerPath()
    }
}

func createShapeLayerPath() {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds,
                            byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight],
                            cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 15.0, height: 15.0))
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.frame = bounds
    layer.mask = shapeLayer
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
}
```

Now everything works, except the fact that if I zoom in, if I look hard I can see e little bit of the underneath view on the corners. They are not perfectly aligned. The bottom line is ok, just the corners.

Comment: Do you use static / automatic height cell ??

Comment: I'm using static height cell of 200. It's declared in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for adding a CAShapeLayer as your view's mask layer is quite close. This line:

```
shapeLayer.frame = bottomDetailsView.frame
```

Should read

```
shapeLayer.frame = bottomDetailsView.bounds
```

View's/layer's frames are expressed in their superview's coordinate system. A view's bounds defines it's coordinate system.

I didn't try your complex table view case, but I did create a subclass of UIView that creates a bottom-rounded mask:

```
class RoundedBottomCornersView: UIView {
    var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer!

    //If the view's bounds change, update the shapeLayer's frame and also rebuild the path
    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            shapeLayer.frame = self.bounds
            createShapeLayerPath()
        }
    }

    func createShapeLayerPath() {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds,
                                byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight],
                                cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 15, height: 15))
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        layer.borderWidth = 1.0

        shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.frame = bounds
        layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        layer.mask = shapeLayer
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint. This approach works, but if I zoom in and look hard I can see just a little bit of the underneath view on the corners. The corner radius is 15.0 on both views. I tried to edit antialiasing on both layers and also `clipsToBounds` on views but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

Your constraints are not sufficient to layout the subviews of the cell as you give containerView

> top , left .right,bottom

and the labels timeLabel

> centerX,Y

titleLabel

> left,right,top

if you looked to these constraints there is no vertical creation of constraints `from` top to bottom , the cell expects it's height from it's subview `containeView` but you do the reverse , so you need to hook the label `titleLabel` top to container (you did) , and it's bottom to the label `timeLabel` top , and the latter's bottom to the bottom of the container , and the container's bottom is already hooked to `contentView` , that's how auto-layout can calculate the right height of the cell , and by this any rounding will show

**BTW :** I don't know your desired design but you have to follow the top-to-bottom hooking of constraints not only to show the rounding but more importantly to show the view that you want to apply the rounding to

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the wrong constraints. The rounded corners did not show even after correcting the constraints, but fixing them also fixed another problem I had because of the poor constraint code.